# Replace null elements from array with some value in MIPS

Tags: arrays, replace, mips

I need something similar with this converted in MIPS. Eventualy using a procedure which gets as parameters the array, the lenght of the array, and the value that should replace the null elements of the array. I also have to print "finish" when done, which I also don't know. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[40];

int main() {
    int i, n = 40; x = 6;
    for (i=0, i<n; i++)
        if (array[i] == 0)
             array[i] = x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Don't need it anymore... It's done, thanks.